# Assembling massive number of PImage not properly working

Tags: image, merge, processing

**Code reworked**

I've written a new code using the ideas given in the responses and tried it on a smaller sample, and still I can't figure out why I have the "heads" not erased on the final result.

The new code look like this :

```
void drawBodyPart(PImage body, PImage bodyPart, String name){
   body.loadPixels();
   bodyPart.loadPixels();
   
   for(int i = 0; i < body.width; i++){
     for(int j = 0; j < body.height; j++){
        int position = i + body.width*j;
        if(alpha(bodyPart.pixels[position]) > 25){
          body.pixels[position] = bodyPart.pixels[position];
        }
     }
   }
   body.updatePixels();
   body.save(folderName + name + ".png");
}
```

And the calling method look like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < humanBodyList.size(); i++){
     for(int j = 0; j < humanHairsList.size(); j++){
         humanBodyList.get(i).loadPixels(); 
         humanBodyList.get(i).updatePixels();
         drawBodyPart(humanBodyList.get(i),  humanHairsList.get(j), "(" + i + "," + j+")");
     }
```

At the end, i've got the first head correcly drawn over the first set of body.
Then i've got the first head, merged with the second one merged with the body.
I even SAVED the intermediary product of body merging... The more I  try the less I understand PImages manipulation in processing.

**----- Old description below -----**

I am working on a little "Processing 3" project where I try to construct some character images basically by merging different body part together. I have :

- a set of "body" images : body1.png, body2.png...
- a set of "head" images : head1.png, head2.png...
- a set of hairs (idem)

Basically what I do is merging "body1 + head1 + hairs1" together to obtain 1 entire body of character.

Each sub-part picture has the same height/width and is mostly transparent except for the part i'm actually interested. So I compare the pixels of 2 said sub-picture, and depending of transparency I keep on of them in the resulting picture. Proceed again for the next body part until every single body part is included in your final picture, then save it.

I do this for every possible combinaison of head, body and hairs. The loop is not the problem (i have the correct number of pictures at the end).
My problem is, some of the picture are just wrong. it's like the buffer of precedent pictures is not empty. As a result you can see the head of the character is in FRONT of some remenants of the hairs of the previous one (see the pictures at the end)

My code look like this :

```
void humanAssembly(PImage head, PImage body, PImage hairs, String name){
   PImage result= body;       
   head.loadPixels();
   body.loadPixels();
   hairs.loadPixels();
   corpsAssemble.loadPixels();
   
     //Merging body and head
   for(int i = 0; i < body.width; i++){
     for(int j = 0; j < body.height; j++){
        int position = i + body.width*j;
        if(alpha(hairs.pixels[position]) > 25){
          result.pixels[position] = hairs.pixels[position];
        }else if(alpha(head.pixels[position]) > 25){
          result.pixels[position] = head.pixels[position];
        }
     }
   }       
   body.updatePixels();
   result.save(imagesRepository + "/generes/" + name+ ".png");
}
```

(Obviously my code is not very efficient, but I dont intend to work on more than a few hundred possibility of very small images, and this code is supposed to run once)

The calling method looks like this:
(inside a triple "for")

```
humanAssembly(listHumanHead.get(i), listHumanBody.get(j), listHumanHairs.get(k), "(" + i + "," + j + "," + k + ")");
```

where "listHumanX" are ArrayList successfully loaded before.

It's probably some silly mistake but I didnt find where it is after quite long time, so i'd appreciate if anyone can help me.
Thanks in advance. anything that works and is understandable by the poor newbie I am is good enough :)

[A correct result : body 1, head 1, hairs 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBP0T.png)

[A correct result : body 1, head 1, hairs 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFVmX.png)

[A correct result : body 1, head 2, hairs 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Eioi.png)

[An icorrect result : body 1, head 2, hairs 1, you still can see the hairs 1 (bald)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aXnzH.png)

Comment: Is "hair 1" the same as "no hair in particular"? It seems like you're drawing in a loop, so if your images are not in the right order, the "default" head may be drawn _over_ the hairs.

Comment: @FrédéricPapadopoulos Indeed, laancelot's hunch appears to be correct. Double check the `hairs` PImage you pass doesn't accidentally contain the image of a head. In terms of efficiency, if `head`,`body` and `hairs` have the exact dimensions a single for loop through the pixels array should do it and you won't need to compute the position index. Additionally you should be able to only `updatePixels()` once at the end. That being said I'd focus on easy to change, readable code before any optimisation...

Comment: ...remember you can also use `PImage`'s [`copy()`](https://processing.org/reference/PImage_copy_.html) method. It will call `updatePixels()` once per image behind the scenes, but pretty much the same performance of your code above. If the images have an alpha channel anyway the if condition can probably go away, otherwise you may want to look into [`blend()`](https://processing.org/reference/PImage_blend_.html) instead of copy. If you need even more flexibility you can [blit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_blit) using [`PGraphics`](https://processing.org/reference/PGraphics.html)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have a few more infos:
- I have reunited my two loops into one.
- I've reduce my "hair" parameters to 1 and now i can see that hairs were not the problem (it wasnt really visible before)
My first loop with 1 defined head + the set of N body does indeed generate N "merged" body.
However when I iterate on the second head and N body again, the result show some traces of the previous head below the new one. As if my "result" variable wasnt cleaned of previous content.
I've checked 3 times every single sprite and sadly there is no forgotten content here to explain it.

Comment: Top layers doesn't "erase" bottom layers, so there is the possibility of the base images not being exactly compatible. Assuming that, in the right order of superposition, the images are compatible, then the best way to insure that they are in the right order would be to force this order. In your case, you can just draw your body parts in the right order, one loop after the other. To stay DRY you may want to create a `drawBodyPart` method which receive the `PImage` and draw it, and in your `humanAssembly` method call this method with every body part from the bottom one to the upper layer.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I'll try to implement this and come back with some feedback as soon as I have something relevant to add !

Comment: Code re-written on simpler example and still the same problem persist. i've editted the description and re-upload some code. If anyone as an idea... i'm getting stuck on this for days now and i'm pretty sure i'm missing something obvious, easy...

Comment: Why are you going through pixel manipulation? Can't you simply display the images on top of each other since they are transparent? I feel like something like this might work: `image(body, 0, 0); image(head, 0, 0); image(hairs, 0, 0);`